# Mongoose model doesn't work well

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

These days, i am working for a project that need to keep some information about analytic by using NodeJS and MongoDB.

When i try to send JSon data, some parts are saved into database but most parts of the data are losing. I couldn't understand where i am doing mistake. I do not have enough background about these technologies.

Here is my Mongoose.model;

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', new Schema({
    unique: Number,
    total: Number,
    hits: {
        String: {
            unique: Number,
            total: Number,
            users:[String]
        }
    }
}));
```

Here is my Create function;

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Product = require('../models/products.models')

/**
 * Create a Product
 */
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var product = new Product(req.body);

    product.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(400);
        else
            res.status(201).json(product);
    });
};
```

Here is what i try to post;

```
{
    "unique" : 50,
    "total" : 150,
    "hits" : {
        "11.06.2015" : {
            "unique" : 50,
            "total" : 60,
            "users" : [ 
                "kris", 
                "mark", 
                "jom", 
                "alpi"
            ]
        },
        "12.06.2015" : {
            "unique" : 50,
            "total" : 90,
            "users" : [ 
                "kris", 
                "mark", 
                "jom"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is being lost/not getting saved?

Comment: @laggingreflex When i try to post above data, "hits" section are not getting saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mongoose type `Mixed`

```
new Schema({
    unique: Number,
    total: Number,
    hits: {}
}
```

**Mixed** An "anything goes" SchemaType, its flexibility comes at a trade-off of it being harder to maintain. 
Mixed is available either through Schema.Types.Mixed or by passing an empty object literal. The following are equivalent:

```
var Person = new Schema({ any: {} });
var Person = new Schema({ any: Schema.Types.Mixed });
```

Since it is a schema-less type, you can change the value to anything else you like, but Mongoose loses the ability to auto detect/save those changes.

**To "tell" Mongoose that the value of a Mixed type has changed, call the .markModified(path) method of the document passing the path to the Mixed type you just changed.**

```
person.anything = { x: [3, 4, { y: "changed" }] };
person.markModified('anything');
person.save(); // anything will now get saved
```

===============
"mongoose": "^4.0.3",
mongodb version v2.6.6

```
var Product = mongoose.model('Products', new mongoose.Schema({
    unique: Number,
    total: Number,
    hits: {}
}));

var product = new Product({
    "unique" : 50,
    "total" : 150,
    "hits" : {
        "11-06-2015" : {
            "unique" : 50,
            "total" : 60,
            "users" : [
                "kris",
                "mark",
                "jom",
                "alpi"
            ]
        },
        "12-06-2015" : {
            "unique" : 50,
            "total" : 90,
            "users" : [
                "kris",
                "mark",
                "jom"
            ]
        }
    }
});
product.save(function(err,p){
   console.log(err,p);
    Product.find(function(err,p){
        console.log(err,p)
    })
})
```

It works correctly for me.
Since mongoose throw an error `[MongoError: key 12.06.2015 must not contain '.']`, I change `12.06.2015` to `12-06-2015`

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. Could't get any response like infinite loop. @Jinceon

Comment: @aeKynr Checkout the edit. And can you describe in more detail the infinite loop error you got this time? Also, did you make sure you used `product.markModified` as suggested in the answer?

Comment: @laggingreflex thanks a lot. There was a problem due to ".(dot)".